# Performing several 1D moving averages in parallel using CUDA Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm not a programmer with any abilities. Just someone curious about CUDA and so I'm doing a little reading. I ran across an example of using Thrust to do a moving average:

[Simple Moving Average Thrust Example](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/simple_moving_average.cu?r=e553df2dbb9e21fb3e95836729139db40b88d07d)

The example, such as it is, runs and mostly works correctly. However it's trivial in the sense that it only does one moving average operation.

How I would do say `352` of these moving average operations in parallel, all operating on the same data stream? In my mind the program flow might be:

1. Generate the data & send it to one CUDA core. (Same as existing code
   but think lengths of `1000` or `10000` instead of `30`)
2. Copy it from the CUDA core it's in to all of the the other `351` CUDA
   cores in my GTX 465
3. Tell each CUDA core what number of data items to average over.
   (`4`, `5`, `6`,..., `352`, `353`, `354`)
4. Tell the device to run the average in each core in parallel
5. Read back the results from each core

I get that this code

```
// compute SMA using standard summation
simple_moving_average(data, w, averages);
```

makes it all happen, but how to I get Thrust to do many of these in parallel?

My interest here is about something like stock data. If I'm looking at GOOG prices I'd put that in the GPU using all cores and leave it there. I'd then be free to do lots of processing without loading the data anymore and just reading back results from each core. NOTE: I might not want to use GOOG in all cores. Some cores might be GOOG, others with some other symbol, but I'll get there later. I'm just thinking I don't want the stock data in global memory if there's enough room in each core.

I assume this is pretty straightforward for CUDA & Thrust?

Comment: The example is built with `exclusive_scan`. I don't know precisely what you require, but perhaps it's possible that one could build something from `exclusive_scan_by_key` to do lots of these operations at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the possible way how to do this with arrayfire: 
Note that I am NOT affiliated with this library whatsoever.
I am pretty sure this can also be done with thrust 
but I found this one a lot simpler with arrayfire. 
And if the library is free why can't I use it instead of thrust ?

In arrayfire you can use matrix to run several SMA operations in parallel:

```
unsigned n_SMAs = 1000;   // # of SMA indicators to evaluate 
unsigned len = 2000;      // # of stock prices per indicator
unsigned w = 6; // window size

// generate stock prices: [0..10] 
af::array data = af::randu(n_SMAs, len) * 10;

// compute inclusive prefix sums along colums of the matrix
af::array s = af::accum(data, 1);

// compute the average
af::array avg = (s.cols(w, af::end) - s.cols(0, af::end - w)) / w;
af::eval(avg);

std::cout << avg.dims() << "\n" << avg << "\n";
```

let me know if that's what you are looking for. This is how I understood your question: compute several SMA indicators in parallel

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are interested into the following two situations:

1. You have a long sequence of items and you want to calculate a certain number of averages, by averaging on different numbers of items, i.e., using different lengths for the moving average window. This is what I understand from your original question.
2. You have a series of sequences, stored consecutively in memory, and you want to average them in parallel with a fixed averaging window of size `2 * RADIUS + 1`. This is what the ArrayFire code proposed by @asm does - you have accepted it.

Instead of using CUDA Thrust, I think it would be easier to write your own CUDA kernel to do the above operations. Below, a fully worked example that operates in the same way as the ArrayFire code proposed by @asm, thus covering case #2. Modifying it to cover case #1 would be straightforward.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#define RADIUS        3
#define BLOCK_SIZE_X  8
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y  8

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/**********/
/* KERNEL */
/**********/
__global__ void moving_average(unsigned int *in, unsigned int *out, unsigned int M, unsigned int N) {

    __shared__ unsigned int temp[BLOCK_SIZE_Y][BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2 * RADIUS];

    unsigned int gindexx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int gindexy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    unsigned int gindex  = gindexy * N + gindexx;

    unsigned int lindexx = threadIdx.x + RADIUS;
    unsigned int lindexy = threadIdx.y;

    // --- Read input elements into shared memory
    temp[lindexy][lindexx] = ((gindexx < N)&&(gindexy < M))? in[gindex] : 0;
    if (threadIdx.x < RADIUS) {
        temp[lindexy][threadIdx.x] = ((gindexx >= RADIUS)&&(gindexx < (N + RADIUS))&&(gindexy < M)) ? in[gindex - RADIUS] : 0;
        temp[lindexy][threadIdx.x + (RADIUS + min(BLOCK_SIZE_X, N - blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X))] = (((gindexx + min(BLOCK_SIZE_X, N - blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X)) < N)&&(gindexy < M))? in[gindexy * N + gindexx + min(BLOCK_SIZE_X, N - blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X)] : 0;
        if ((threadIdx.y == 0)&&(gindexy < M)&&((gindexx + BLOCK_SIZE_X) < N)&&(gindexy < M)) printf("Inside 2 - tidx = %i; bidx = %i; tidy = %i; bidy = %i; lindexx = %i; temp = %i\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x, threadIdx.y, blockIdx.y, threadIdx.x + (RADIUS + BLOCK_SIZE_X), temp[lindexy][threadIdx.x + (RADIUS + BLOCK_SIZE_X)]);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // --- Apply the stencil
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (int offset = -RADIUS ; offset <= RADIUS ; offset++) {
        result += temp[lindexy][lindexx + offset];
    }

    // --- Store the result
    out[gindexy * N + gindexx] = result;
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const unsigned int M        = 2;
    const unsigned int N        = 4 + 2 * RADIUS;

    const unsigned int constant = 3;

    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> d_in(M * N, constant);
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> d_out(M * N);

    dim3 GridSize(iDivUp(N, BLOCK_SIZE_X), iDivUp(M, BLOCK_SIZE_Y));
    dim3 BlockSize(BLOCK_SIZE_X, BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
    moving_average<<<GridSize, BlockSize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_in.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_out.data()), M, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    thrust::host_vector<unsigned int> h_out = d_out;

    for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            printf("Element j = %i; i = %i; h_out = %i\n", j, i, h_out[N*j+i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```